Bind entity property using sql function in EF Core
I have a SQL function which returns some calculated value for a column:
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_GetCustomValue] 
    (@Id int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN
    -- some calculation and joins
END

Then I have an entity
[Table("Country")]
public partial class Country
{
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Desc { get; set; }
       public string CustomDesc { get; set; }  // here this should be a response from the SQK function
}

I have this query to return all countries:
public IQueryable<Country> GetCountries(dbContext context)
{
    return context.Countries; 
}

How do I get countries with custom desc calculated from that SLQ function?

You can't map a single string to multiple objects. f_GetCustomValue returns a single string value but you're trying to map it to multiple values and make the queryable too. What are you actually trying to do? Did you create a function that returns results as a JSON or XML string? That's a bad idea. That string can't be queried or mapped. It has to be parsed and any operations will have to be done on the server. You gain no flexibility, only a ton of problems. That's why this solution was abandoned by 2010, killed by ... ORMs among others

To be brutally honest, you probably shouldn't be using a scalar function anyway as they are terribly slow. Instead create a view with the joins you need and map that in EF Core.

Agree wih charlieface. The and joins part of -- some calculation and joins gives me the heebie jeebies

EF supports computed columns on tables, but if you have a set of related entities and want to summarize some related data it is better to use projection to fetch your data. for example if I have an Order which has a reference to a Customer via a CustomerId and in my Order I want to display the CustomerName (Customer.FirstName + Customer.LastName) I don't add a CustomerName to my Order table, so it doesn't make any sense to add a CustomerName to my Order entity. What I can do is read a projection through EF using the Order and the related Customer via a navigation property:
public class OrderSummaryViewModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; } 
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

Then when I read these order results:
var orders = _context.Orders
    //.Where(conditions)
    .Select(x => new OrderSummaryViewModel
    {
        OrderId = x.OrderId,
        CustomerId = x.Customer.CustomerId,
        OrderNumber = x.OrderNumber,
        CustomerName = x.Customer.FirstName + " " + x.Customer.LastName
   }).ToList();

These mapping rules can be set up in a mapper config such as Automapper or Mapperly where the Select() can be replaced by a .ProjectTo<OrderSummaryViewModel>(config) or similar for a one-liner.
If you have a function in mind that pulls information from related tables, ensure the entity relations are expressed through navigation properties then project a desired output view model with the summarized details.
Alternatively if you have a need to build a common, read-only summary of related data for search results or reporting, you can compose a database View for the desired output and map an entity to the View rather than the tables. I would not recommend having a view call a scalar function for mapping a related field, just perform the necessary joins to ensure indexing and such are utilized.
